# how to check textarea has edit or not

Tags: php, tinymce, textarea

Hello i am using tinymce as Editor on text area , But i have problem to check IF text area text change or not , as i load it from database to javascript , what i found that Editor not update content changed to html , so when i check with javascript , it said still same no change

script to load editor

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: ".editor",
    plugins: [
        "image",
    ],
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am sorry to answer my question after long time ,
put here how i can detect change of value to tinymce TextArea

```
 textArea = '<?php if (isset($course['description'])) echo $course['description']; ?>';
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(eventObject) {
    returnValue = undefined;
    if (!isSave) {

        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            if (values[i] != inputs[i].value) {
                returnValue = "";
            }
        }
        tinyMCE.triggerSave();
        if (tinymce.get('description').getContent() != textArea) {
            returnValue = "";
        }
    }
    eventObject.returnValue = returnValue;
    return returnValue;
});
```